# Workflow to manage different input files with rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio

I'm switching from R to python's rasterio and would like to get your experience in how to best manage different input files. I want to do various calculations, but I'm facing a problem in aligning my rasters.

Goal: 'Aligning' different input files, so they can be read as arrays with the same shape.

In R, I would just create a template and then apply this to the different input files

```
country_template <- raster()
country_template <- setExtent(country_template, dimensions, crs etc)
...

slope<- projectRaster(slope, country_template, 
       crs = 'xyz',res = yxz)
```

In rasterio, I have tried to use `rio warp` to get matching resolution and crs of the two input files, but my arrays still have different shapes.

I tried

```
command_string = 'rio warp {} {} --res {}'.format(os.getcwd()+input, os.getcwd()+output ,res)
os.popen(command_string).read()

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1196,2264) (3764,6736)
```

How can I fix this?